# JMeter: Changing "think-time" at run time

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter the main goal of using timers is simulating a virtual user’s “think time”. Is this possible to run a test that can dynamically change think-time at user's will in order to test a particular behavior of multi-threaded application. For example if i define Poisson Random Timer for my test and at the run time I want to load the server with burst of request with heavy-tailed distribution and for this purpose i want to switch from Poisson to Guassian distribution(e.g.) then what i have to do during  preparing a Test Plan or what I can do during test is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change timers implementation, but in terms of constant delays and offsets - this is something you can change in the runtime.

1. Define "think times" using JMeter properties having some reasonable default values via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(think-time,5)}`
2. When your test is running you can control `think-time` property value via [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server) increasing or decreasing it according to your test scenario.

See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) article for more detailed explanation on using timers in JMeter tests.